# How can i repeat MySQL's WHERE 1 query in MongoDB?

Tags: mysql, mongodb, express, mongoose

I can do this in MySQL:

```
WHERE 1 AND 1 AND 1
```

How can i repeat it in MongoDB? What is MongoDB's equivalent for WHERE 1 ?

**UPDATE:**

So. I don't know how choose best answer ^^ and expanded question. As @mark-hillick noticed - i'm searching the best way to build query.
Now I'm using this way (express+mongoose):

```js
//req.query - get/post object in Express

for (var q in req.query) {
  if (req.query[q]) { //simplified example
    query[q] = req.query[q];
  };
}

Collection.find(query)
```

Your suggestions?

Comment: for the update: It depends on how far you wish to take the "easy" way of building queries. This won't work very well for more complex structures such as $ors and $ands since you will still have to write those out fully. Also you are taking the query elements directly from POST/GET? no sanitation?

Comment: To add another point, since I cannot edit my original comment: in fact a person can maliciously inject a $or and an $and with that code to change the way your query will work.

Answer (score 1):

There is a SQL-MongoDB Mapping Chart [here](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/SQL+to+Mongo+Mapping+Chart) that you will find useful.

It has a tonne of examples on what you do within MongoDB when you want to do the same operation as "WHERE" in MySQL. For example -

```
SELECT a,b FROM users WHERE age=33
```

is

```
db.users.find({age:33}, {a:1,b:1})
```

or

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE a=1 and b=1
```

is

```
db.users.find({a:1,b:1})
```

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB is document oriented database and documents in MongoDB consists key-value pairs. So, in MongoDB you can't run single value query as you did in MySql. Assuming you hold your data in the field name a, similar query in MongoDB could be like :

```
db.test.find({$and : [{a:1},{a:1}, {a:1}]});
```

Answer (score 0):

If' you're trying to build query clauses, AND is implicit in Mongo. Therefore, if you have the following;

```
db.col.find({name:"dave"})
```

you could just add another;

```
db.col.find({name:"dave", age:33})
```

and so on.

Comment: Yes I do. But 'm searching the best way to build query. Now i'm doing it [this way](http://jsfiddle.net/vawerv/DNcTw/)

Comment: Yep. That looks good to me, assuming you sanitise your input (don't blindly pass through request parameters into Mongo)

Comment: Sure. It's simplified example =)

Comment: Then I think you have your answer!